# Android App crashing on Back Button (performResumeActivity)

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, resume

My App consists of 2 Activities at the moment.
. the MAIN activity with a Gallery View
. a FriendsListActivity with a ListView

When the user moves away from the FriendsListActivity with the back button, and returns to the MAIN activity the following error keeps popping up in debug mode.

> DalvikVM[localhost:8676]      Thread [<1>
>   main] (Suspended (exception
>   RuntimeException))
>         ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(IBinder,
>   boolean) line: 2095
>         ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(IBinder,
>   boolean, boolean) line: 2110
>         BinderProxy(ActivityThread$H).handleMessage(Message)
>   line: 954 
>         ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message)
>   line: 99          Looper.loop() line: 123 
>         ActivityThread.main(String[]) line:
>   3647          Method.invokeNative(Object,
>   Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native
>   method]           Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 507
>         ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
>   line: 839         ZygoteInit.main(String[])
>   line: 597 
>         NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not
>   available [native method]     Thread
>   [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running)
>     Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1]
>   (Running)

With the LogCat

> 03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   resume activity
>   {com.package.MAIN/com.package.MAIN.MAIN}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-13
>   22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:954)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) 03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-13
>   22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   com.package.MAIN.MAIN.onResume(MAIN.java:91)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3833)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
>   03-13 22:01:10.972:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1038):     ... 10
>   more

Further info in the Variables panel states:
this: ActivityThread
e: NullPointerException
cause: NullPointerException
detailMessage: null
stackTrace: null
r: ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord
activity: MAIN

detailMessage after one Eclipse Resume: Unable to resume activity (MAIN)

The code from the FriendsListActivity looks like this

```
public class FriendsListActivity extends ListActivity {

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
private FriendsArrayAdapter friendsArrayAdapter;
private ListView listView;

// ===========================================================
// onCreate
// ===========================================================

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.friends_list);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    setButtonNewFriendClickListener();
}

public void generateFriendsList() {
    FriendsService fs = new FriendsService(this);
    friends = fs.getFriendsList();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    friendsArrayAdapter = new FriendsArrayAdapter(
       this, R.layout.friend_list_item, friends);
    listView.setAdapter(friendsArrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.friends_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    FriendsService fs = new FriendsService(this);
    Friend f = new Friend();
    f = friends.get(info.position);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.edit:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, FriendEditActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("userid", f.userId);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    case R.id.delete:
        fs.deleteFriend(f.userId);
        generateFriendsList();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// ===========================================================
// onPause
// ===========================================================

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

// ===========================================================
// onResume
// ===========================================================

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    generateFriendsList();
}

// ===========================================================
// onStop
// ===========================================================

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

// ===========================================================
// onDestroy
// ===========================================================

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

// ===========================================================
// Activity methods
// ===========================================================

private void setButtonNewFriendClickListener() {
    Button clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add_friend);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), FriendNewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

The AndroidManifest looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" package="com.package.mypackage">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.package.mypackage.mypackage"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name=".FriendsListActivity"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".FriendEditActivity"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".FriendNewActivity"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".TakePictureActivity"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".FriendsService"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".MyService"></activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
```

The MAIN activity looks like this:

```
    package com.package.mypackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.package.domain.Domain;
import com.package.service.MyService;
import com.package.viewadapter.myImageAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class myActivity extends Activity {

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private MyImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
private ArrayList<Domain> domain = new ArrayList<Domain>();

// ===========================================================
// onCreate
// ===========================================================

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* Set Buttons to listen for any click event. */
    setButtonFriendsClickListener();
    setButtonCameraClickListener();
    setButtonPreferencesClickListener();
}

// ===========================================================
// onStart
// ===========================================================

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    /* Find the gallery defined in the main.xml */        
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    /* Show a Toast message when image is clicked */
    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            MyImageAdapter image_ID = new MyImageAdapter(myActivity.this, position, null);
            if (image_ID.getItemId(position) == 0) {
                Toast test_toast = Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "This is the New Image click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                test_toast.show();
            }
            else {
                Toast test_toast = Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "The clicked image has image number " + image_ID.getItemId(position) + " in the imageadapter.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                test_toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

    g.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            MyImageAdapter image_ID = new MyImageAdapter(myActivity.this, position, null);
            Toast test_toast = Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "The long clicked image has image number " + image_ID.getItemId(position) + " in the imageadapter.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            test_toast.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

// ===========================================================
// onPause
// ===========================================================

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

// ===========================================================
// onResume
// ===========================================================

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    generateMyGallery();
}

// ===========================================================
// onStop
// ===========================================================

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

// ===========================================================
// onDestroy
// Is also called when user changes from horizontal
// to vertical orientation and back
// ===========================================================

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

// ===========================================================
// Save and Restore UI states
// ===========================================================

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

// ===========================================================
// Main Activity methods
// ===========================================================


public void generateMyGallery() {
    MyService cs = new MyService(this);
    domain = cs.getDomainList();

    // Add the new_image drawable to the ArrayList
    Domain d = new Domain();
    d.photoLocation = "drawable";
    d.photoName = "new_image";
    d.extra1 = "no_text";
    d.extra2 = "no_text";
    domain.add(0, d);

    myImageAdapter = new MyImageAdapter(this, R.layout.text_overlay_image_view, domain);

    /* Find the gallery defined in the main.xml */        
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setSpacing(10);

    /* Apply a new (custom) ImageAdapter to it. */
    g.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
    g.setSelection(1);
}

private void setButtonFriendsClickListener() {
    Button clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_friends_list);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.friends_list);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FriendsListActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

private void setButtonCameraClickListener() {
    Button clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_take_picture);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.take_picture);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), TakePictureActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

private void setButtonPreferencesClickListener() {
    Button clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_preferences);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyPreferencesActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    }
};
```

Anyone has an idea why the App crashes. Any help is much appreciated.

I did find out that, when I finish() the MAIN activity when I start the FriendListActivity and restart the MAIN activity when closing the FriendListActivity, that the crash does not occur. However, this basically restarts the App and that is not the intention.

---

Thanks all, I got the problem solved. This is what I did.
. When moving all gallery related actions to the onCreate, the creash didn't happen anymore. But then after returning to the MAIN activity, the activity wasn't shown.
. I then moved all the onCreate (except the super), the generateGallery, and the onStart() to the onResume. Now it works fine!

Comment: I think problem is in onCreate() method of the MAIN activity with a Gallery View.

Comment: I now also listed the onCreate() method from the MAIN activity. I believe the app crashes in recreating the MAIN activity. Thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

why do you call in onPause() finish()?

have you tried to comment it out?

And what is this friendservice?

Possibly it causes your exception.

**UPD:**

I would say, move generateMyGallery(); from onResume into onCreate. Because everytime the user comes back from another activity onResume will be called. And so generateMyGallery() as well

Comment: I just wanted to nicely close the Activity before returning to the old MAIN activity. When I removed the finish() it didn't solve the problem. The Friendservice is a Service to get the data from a database. Also closing the Friendservice with fs.finish() after using is didn't help.

Comment: i think, it's not good idea to use finish in onPause. And have you tried to comment all using of your service? just to be sure, this service doesn't cause the crash

Comment: I would say, move generateMyGallery(); from onResume into onCreate. Because everytime the user comes back from another activity onResume will be called. And so generateMyGallery() as well